# How to get a number after a word out of a url using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a url, in it I have  `NotificationId=2418`, I need to pull out that number obviously anything can be before and after that. Pulling out `NotificationId` i can do but how can i pull the number after? I am using Java.

Comment: what language do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this pattern:

```
NotificationId=([0-9]+)
```

and then extract the content of the first capturing group.

Other method: using a lookbehind:

```
(?<=NotificationId=)[0-9]+
```

A lookbehind `(?<=...)` is a zero-width assertion that means *followed by*

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on @CasimiretHippolyte's answer and Java-fy it, here's some code you can use:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SandboxTest {

    @Test
    public void testGroups() {
        assertEquals("2418", method("NotificationId=2418"));
    }

    private String method(String s) {
        Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("NotificationId=(\\d+)");
        Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No match found");
        }
    }


}
```